# Outlook Rules: Specific Domain not working

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, rules

I am attempting to create a rule in the Outlook 365 App (Not OWA) to move all internal company emails from the inbox to an internal folder.

I have attempted the rules settings as follows:

```
Apply this rule after the message arrives
from @domain.com
move it to the folder Internal Emails folder
and stop processing more rules
```

```
Apply this rule after the message arrives
with @domain.com in the recipient's address
move it to the folder Internal Emails folder
and stop processing more rules
```

```
Apply this rule after the message arrives
with @domain.com in the sender's address
move it to the folder Internal Emails folder
and stop processing more rules
```

Note 1: The rule works for external emails/mailservers that use our domain, but does not work internally.

Note 2: I can create individual rules for internal users and it works. However blanket domain rules do not work.

EDIT 24/11/2021

I have run the rule in OWA and it also did not work.
I have attached a section of report I generated after running it.
Note the only thing changed is the name of the domain, and the hex value that indicates the name of the domain.

```
<Rule
            Index="1"
            Name="mnl_Internal"
            Id="10546516418390654977"
            Provider="RuleOrganizer"
            ExecutionSequence="10"
            Level="0"
            IsExtended="False"
            StateFlags="ExitAfterExecution"
            UserFlags="0">
            <ProviderData><![CDATA[
00000000 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 07 40 77 4C BE E0 D7 01    |.........@wL....|
]]></ProviderData>
            <Restriction
                Type="Content"
                ContentFlags="SubString / 00000001"
                PropTag="SenderSearchKey / 000000000C1D0102"
                MultiValued="False">
                <Property
                    Id="SenderSearchKey / 000000000C1D0102"
                    DataType="Binary / 0102">
                    <Value><![CDATA[
00000000 45 58 41 4D 50 4C 45 2E 43 4F 4D 2E 41 55           |EXAMPLE.COM.AU       |
]]></Value>
                </Property>
            </Restriction>
            <Actions>
                <Action
                    Type="OP_MOVE"
                    UserFlags="00000000"
                    FolderName="Internal Emails">
                    <FolderEntry><![CDATA[
00000000 00 00 00 00 DE 49 BD 39 5E E1 D7 4E 86 CB EC A5    |.....I.9^..N....|
00000010 24 66 CF 08 01 00 E6 A6 C9 4C BE 4D C2 44 94 DF    |$f.......L.M.D..|
00000020 D6 FA BB E3 A3 3F 00 00 01 A5 CA 8B 00 00          |.....?........  |
]]></FolderEntry>
                    <StoreEntry />
                </Action>
            </Actions>
        </Rule>
```

Comment: Do you mean that you want to create a rule to move emails from several domains?

Comment: I am writing to see if there is any progress on the issue. If you have any questions or need further help on this, feel free to post back.

Comment: Apologies for the delay.

No in this case I am trying to do it for a specific domain. So one single rule to apply to ALL emails in a specific domain

Example:
email1@domain.com
email2@domain.com
email3@domain.com

I want a rule like *@domain.com to apply to all the emails above.

However the rule attempts above have not worked internally. (however it works externally)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I noticed that you have added a condition "stop processing more rules". Consider whether you have previously created some rules related to this domain, which will have an impact on the mail you currently create to move messages from this domain to the internal folder. Please check your other rules.

Comment: Hi, there are no other rules, however they step has never impacted rules before. It applies only to that rule I believe.

Comment: I have the feeling "with specific words in the recipient's address" will not work in combination with domain names because domain names are not shown, it only shows the name like "surname, firstname". Eg. if I export a mail as a txt file it will also be exported without the domain name.

Answer (score 0):

To further confirm the problem, please provide the following information:

- What's the type of your account(POP/IMAP/Exchange)?
- And does other users in your organization can create and apply the same rule?

According to my test on my Outlook client 365 version(version2110(Build 14527.20234 click-to-run)), the rule created to move the emails from the internal domain to a specific folder can work successfully. What's the version of your Outlook? (File > Office Account > About Outlook). Please make sure you have upgraded your Outlook to the latest version.

[image]

Considering the current data file or profile may be damaged, it is suggested that you could try to create a new profile(control panel>mail>show profile>add) and do the same test to check if there are some differences.

In addition, antivirus software may conflict with outlook. It is suggested that you could temporarily close your antivirus software and restart outlook to check whether this issue still exists.

Comment: My account type is Exchange (Microsoft 365)

I have not been able to confirm if others are capable of doing this.

I have copied your rules verbatim and the issue still occurs.

Outlook is running 2109 build (so only one version behind).

This is on a new profile, (No it wasn't working on the old one either), as I am on a new PC.

Comment: To further confirm whether the problem is related to the outlook 365 client, please try creating the same rule on web mail to check whether it works normally. In addition, I think you could contact other users in your organization and confirm whether you can create rules consistent with you. If others are the same, the issue may be related to the same setting in your current organization, please contact your administrator for further understanding.

Comment: Have not made it in the web client yet. However further note on this, the rule works if I set the rule to active. So when I receive new emails, but it doesn’t work manually. I want it to work manually though. So I am unsure. I tried another approach we have a company wide Group but that also doesn’t work manually.

Comment: Note, I have made an update to the original question, with more info with InboxRules.txt file generated using the OWA running the rule.